# Iterate through content and retrieve values

Tags: php, extract

I have a list of properties like this:

```
1000 Rope Bend Ter
Labelle, FL 33935
Hendry County
15811 Hendry Isles Blvd
Clewiston, FL 33440
Hendry County
```

Now I need to extract the 1st line, and place it in a MySQL database under address field, then extract the city (which is always the 2nd and has a comma after it), extract the state and ZIP, placing them under appropriate MySQL columns.

So, basically, one address is in 3 rows and in the format shown above. Address, line break, City, State, ZIP, line break county (I don't need county info).

Can somebody give a tip how to extract it properly?

Comment: If you'll show us your code, we'll be able help.

Comment: No code my friend - I am using the simple html dom to extract content from another site and I am getting response as described. Anyway - h2ooooooo solution works great.... THANKS ALL !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***: Updated the Regex

The Regex `/^([^ ]+)\s*(.+)\s+([^,]+),\s*([^ ]+)\s*(.+)\s*(.+)/im` should work.

The way to use that in PHP is:

```
<?php
    $string = "1000 Rope Bend Ter\r\nLabelle, FL 33935\r\nHendry County\r\n15811 Hendry Isles Blvd\r\nClewiston, FL 33440\r\nHendry County";
    preg_match_all("/^([^ ]+)\s*(.+)\s+([^,]+),\s*([^ ]+)\s*(.+)\s*(.+)/im", $string, $matches);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        echo "Street number: " . $matches[1][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "Street name: " . $matches[2][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "City: " . $matches[3][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "State: " . $matches[4][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "Zip: " . $matches[5][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "County: " . $matches[6][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "<br /><br />";
    }
?>
```

---

**Output:**

```
Street number: 1000
Street name: Rope Bend Ter 
City: Labelle
State: FL
Zip: 33935 
County: Hendry County

Street number: 15811
Street name: Hendry Isles Blvd 
City: Clewiston
State: FL
Zip: 33440 
County: Hendry County
```

If you need the Regex explained, just say so.

Comment: Very cool, thanks - I used this to pack it in arrays :) THANKS !